# Why can't I copy files to a remote PC via clipboard using the Remote Desktop application?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, file-transfer, copy-paste, clipboard

I have two machines running **Windows 10**. With this version of Windows a new version of the "**Remote Desktop**" utility was added, replacing the older "**Remote Desktop Connection**" utility.

I am using my main PC to connect to the other one using "Remote Desktop". Now, I can share the clipboard between the two machines, to copy chunks of text back and forth. However, I am unable to copy files using the clipboard (neither using `Ctrl-C/V`, `Ctrl-Ins/Shift-Ins` or the GUI options of "**Windows Explorer**").

In the options for this connection, I have the "**Local resources / Clipboard**" switch set to "On".

This feature was working with the older utility. I have `rdpclip.exe` process running on the remote machine.

How can I enable file copy between the two machines using **Remote Desktop**?

**Update 1:** I found out that I can copy files from the remote machine to the local machine, but I still cannot copy from local to remote. Also, I don't know if the two utilities are connected in any way, but in the old app, I enabled the **Local Resources** / **Local devices and resources** / **More...** / **Drives** / **Windows (C:)** checkbox in both machines.

**Update 2:** I tried connecting with the old application. Using that one I am able to copy files. The problem is somehow in the **Remote Connection** settings.

Comment: Check on your local PC in Settings > Privacy > File system > Choose which apps can access your file system?

By default, the new Remote Desktop windows store app (URDC) has this access disabled, but it should warn you the first time you try to paste a file to the remote server.

As far as the remote computer is concerned, there shouldn't be anything to change if the older Remote Desktop (RDC or `mstsc.exe`) is working properly

Comment: @Cpt.Whale - Thanks, I wasn't aware of this "File system" setting. I tried all 4 combinations of enabled/disabled on both machines with no luck. Currently, on both sides all the permissions in that section are enabled, but I cannot copy files from local to remote, and interestingly, now I cannot copy from remote to local either. Go figure...

Comment: This may also be related to the fact that these are two corporate machines, but from my experience, when a feature setting is blocked from user (managed by admins only), then it is greyed out, and this is not the situation here.

Comment: It's possible, but that also seems unlikely if it's working in RDC, and those settings usually apply to copying text as well. You could try toggling the filesystem access setting off and back on (requires restarting the app), or fully reinstalling URDC?

Comment: Are you able to copy text in your desired direction? You can use a hack like this one: https://bukhantsov.org/2019/09/27/copy-exe-as-text-via-clipboard-to-a-remote-desktop/

Comment: @Marcel - this is a nice idea. The files I am copying are big binary executables, I am not sure the clipboard is big enough to hold their (textual) version.

Comment: @ysap With up to a few dozen MB's I had good success with copying text around in Winodws RDP environments and using the aforementioned hack. And if it's really a problem, you could also split the "text" up as a last resort.